# $\sum_{r=0}^{100}{100\choose r}\sin(2rx)$ and $\sum_{r=0}^{100}{100\choose r}\cos(2rx)$

Tags: complex-numbers, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> My textbook without any reasoning, writes the simplified form of $\sum_{r=0}^{100}{100\choose r}\sin(2rx)$ as $2^{101}\cos^{100}x\sin(100x)$ and $\sum_{r=0}^{100}{100\choose r}\cos(2rx)$ as $2^{101}\cos^{100}x\cos(100x)$.

I have tried writing out the binomial expansion to $(\cos(2rx)+i\sin(2rx))^{n}$, but not sure of that would help. Any hints on how to prove this result, or whether any citation to a known such identity would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it is $2^{101}$ and not $2^{100}$? I evaluated and get $2^{100}$ there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it the other way around - let $z=e^{2ix}$, then
$$\sin 2rx=\frac1{2i}(z^r-z^{-r})$$
Now the $z^r$ give one binomial sum, and the $z^{-r}$ give another

Comment: I tried using this, but I seem to getting the power of $2$ as $100$. Here is what I did: $$\begin{aligned}\sum_{r=0}^{100}{100\choose r}\cos(2rx)&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{r=0}^{100}{100\choose r}(z^{r}+z^{-r}), z=\exp(2ix) \\&=\frac{1}{2}(1+z^{-100})(1+z)^{100} \\ &= \frac{1}{2}(1+\cos(200x)-i\sin(200x))(1+\cos(2x)+i\sin(2x))^{100}\\&=2^{100} \cos^{100}x\cos(100x)\end{aligned}$$

Comment: You should get (1/2) [(1+z)^100 + (1+z^-1)^100].  Let y=e^ix, then z=y^2, and (z+1)=(y+1/y)*y = (2cos x)e^ix, and 1+1/z = (2cos x)e^-ix